# Delete lines in python between marks

Tags: python

I have several config files that are created dynamically with a format like this:

```
line1
line2
lines.....
# BEGIN TAG1
foo
foo
foo
# END TAG1
# BEGIN TAG2
bar
bar
bar
# END TAG2
lines
lines
lines
```

I need to delete the lines between BEGIN and END for a specific TAG (i.e.: between BEGIN TAG1 and END TAG1, how can i do this with python?. I have done this before with sed:

```
sed -n '/# BEGIN i-83/,/# END i-83/!p'
```

But I didn't found the way with python and I prefer doesn't make system calls to launch sed from python.

The result should be like this one:

```
line1
line2
lines.....
# BEGIN TAG2
bar
bar
bar
# END TAG2
lines
lines
lines
```

Best regards

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this,

```
with open(file) as f:
    m = True
    for line in f:
        if 'BEGIN TAG1' in line:
            m = False
        elif 'END TAG1' in line:
            m = True
            continue
        if m:
            print (line, end="")
```